# When sending a link in the messenger, the preview is displayed in only one language

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

When sending a link to the messenger, the preview is generated in one language, regardless of the selected language on the site.
The code works correctly, in the developer panel the meta description is displayed according to the selected language, but the messenger still displays everything in one language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be sure your meta fields descriptions (`<meta property="og:description">` `<meta name="Description">` etc.) are generated accordingly to selected language and stored inside html (see via "View page source code").

If this works maybe browser/messenger cache takes place, please test open graph information using any third-party free tools